# Make [data-visualization] a synonym of [visualization]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

[visualization](/questions/tagged/visualization) and [data-visualization](/questions/tagged/data-visualization) appear to be used to refer to the same concept, though any individual question appears usually to favour one over the other.

I think `visualization` is well-enough understood to make the `data-` superfluous, so the latter should be a synonym of the former; the proportion of questions with each tag seems to agree.

Comment: What if we are visualizing something else? (i.e. waveforms, etc.) I see that most questions in [tag:visualization] are **not** like this, but this is a slightly different concept.

Comment: I suppose it depends how broad your interpretation of "data" is :) I'd certainly extend it to waveforms, the data in their case (as in many other cases) being a collection of samples.

Comment: True. I guess in my head I was separating out static vs. dynamic/live visualization, but that was silly of me. I rescind my comment.

Comment: The proposed synonym has a vote score of -1.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That bodes well :P Thanks for the update!